# Error after setting up Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I am upgrading vagrant 1.7.4 on my mac 10.9.5

After installing it, and running "vagrant -v", I got this error:

-bash: /usr/bin/vagrant: No such file or directory

I tried a couple of solutions but none worked:

- Reinstalled VirtualBox (5.0.4), then reinstalling vagrant
- changed permission the dir:
  sudo chown -R davidpell /usr/bin/vagrant

Comment: how did you install ? can you check if its present in `/usr/local/bin` ?

Comment: I got through that part, by resetting the disk permissions on my mac.  I reinstalled virtualbox and vagrant.  But now getting this error:

**SMB shared folders are only available when Vagrant is running
on Windows. The guest machine can be running non-Windows. Please use another synced folder type.**  

I can't find any results when I google search for an answer. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: do you have something like `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "smb"` ? make sure not to use `smb` sharing folder type, as said can only be used if your host is on windows - maybe you can paste your whole Vagrantfile

Comment: Here is the code :  I do see a parameter for "SMB".  SO wont let accept that much text in the comment

  config.vm.provider :hyperv do |v, override|
    override.vm.synced_folder "www/", "/srv/www/", :owner => "www-data", :mount_options => ["dir_mode=0775","file_mode=0774","forceuid","noperm","nobrl","mfsymlinks"]
    # Change all the folder to use SMB instead of Virtual Box shares
    config.vm.synced_folders.each do |id, options|
      if ! options[:type]
        options[:type] = "smb"
      end
    end
  end

Comment: ok so you can remove this part `config.vm.synced_folders.each do |id, options| if ! options[:type] options[:type] = "smb" end` so you will leave the default and will be good to go

Answer (score 3):

I think I encountered the same problem when upgrading from Vagrant 1.6.5 to 1.8.5 and it appears to be due to an old symlink from /usr/bin/vagrant -> /Applications/Vagrant/bin/vagrant

My solution was to:

1. remove old symlink:

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/bin/vagrant
   ```
2. recreate symlink to location of vagrant 1.8.5:

   ```
   sudo ln -s  /usr/local/bin/vagrant /usr/bin/vagrant
   ```

vagrant 1.8.5 or something in my system held-over from 1.6.x seems to depend on /usr/bin/vagrant, because even executing `/usr/local/bin/vagrant` directly failed with `-bash: /usr/bin/vagrant: No such file or directory` prior to recreating the symlink.